# LINQ - adding function to datacontext

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext, stringbuilder

I have a linq table "KUND" who is read only to me. It has some special characters in it to which i have writter a function to switch them out to the ones i want.

```
public static string changeSpecialCharacters(string kund)
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(kund);

        b = b.Replace("Õ", "å");
        b = b.Replace("┼", "Å");
        b = b.Replace("õ", "ä");
        b = b.Replace("─", "Ä");
        b = b.Replace("÷", "ö");
        b = b.Replace("Í", "Ö");
        b = b.Replace("'", " ");
        b = b.Replace("¦", "´");
        b = b.Replace("Ï", "Ø");

        return b.ToString();
    }
```

I now have two questions:

1 Can i add this function to the GET in the autogenerated datacontext so i dont have to call it all over my code? Ive added it but it seems to be deleted whenever i change how my datacontext is (add/remove table). 2 Any suggestions how to make that function better in regards to speed perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never edit the .designer.cs; instead, add a *second* file, and use `partial class` to add the method, for example:

```
namespace Your.Namespace
{
    partial class YourDataContext
    {
        // your methods here
    }
}
```

No; you can't add this to the get. Another alternative, though, is an *extension* method:

```
namespace Some.Utility.Namespace
{
    public static class SomeUtilityClass
    {
        public static string ChangeSpecialCharacters(this string kund)
        { ... } // note the "this" in the above line
    }
}
```

Now you can use:

```
string name = obj.Name.ChangeSpecialCharacters();
```

personally I would rename this to clarify the *direction* of the change, and have two methods - one to encode, one to decode.

---

Re doing this for a set of data; perhaps:

```
public static IEnumerable<SomeType> ChangeSpecialCharacters(
    this IEnumerable<SomeType> items)
{
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        item.Name = item.Name.ChangeSpecialCharacters();
        item.Foo = item.Foo.ChangeSpecialCharacters();
        ...
        item.Bar = item.Bar.ChangeSpecialCharacters();
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: How could i do this on the entire object instead? Kinda like `List<KUND> kunder = new List<KUND>().changeSpecialCharacters();`

Comment: @Andreas - you would write an extension method on `List<KUND>` (or maybe `IEnumerable<KUND>` that loops over the records changing the necessary properties

Comment: could you provide a code example on that? I have never dont it and cant get it to work while trying..

Comment: Cant use item.Name = item.Name.ChangeSpecialCharacters(): because its read only...

Answer (score 0):

probably you could initialize your variable as:

```
private string kund;
public string Kund
{
    get
    {
        return changeSpecialCharacters(string kund);
    }
    set
    {
        kund = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if i get a List<KUND> and then databind it...then i have no way to use the ext method do i? Can i make the ext method to loop over all items in it and call the function? So i could be able to do this    List<KUNDs> kunder = new new List<KUNDs>().changeSpecialCharacters(); ?